# Calculating integral of step function

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1: One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

> *Page 70. Exercise 10.* Given a positive integer $p$. A step function $s$ is defined on the interval $[0,p]$ as follows: $s(x)=(-1)^nn$ if $x$ lies in the interval $n\le x<n+1$, where $n=0,1,2,\cdots,p-1;$ $s(p)=0$. Let $f(p)=\int_0^ps(x)\mathrm dx.$
>
> a) Calculate $f(3),f(4)$ and $f(f(3)).$
>
> b) For what value (or values) of $p$ is $|f(p)|=7$?

*The attempt at a solution.* As I understood, $s(x)=(-1)^nn$ can also be expressed as $s(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor$, and graph of that step function is:

[image]

Here, $$f(3)=\int_0^3((-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor)\mathrm dx=2-1=1,$$ $$f(4)=\int_0^4((-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor)\mathrm dx=2-1-3=-2,$$ $$f(f(3))=\int_0^1((-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor)\mathrm dx=0,$$

But answers in the book say that $f(4)=-1$, where am I making mistake or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I can't personally see why $f(4)\neq -2$.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Do you see any reason why $s(x)=(-1)^nn$ as defined in the question is not same as floor function $s(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor$? If they are the same, then I guess answer is incorrect in the book, since $f(4)=\int_0^4((-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor x\rfloor)\mathrm dx=2-1-3=-2$ is clearly correct.

Comment: If you wanted confirmation, the answer Apostol provides in the back of the book is indeed incorrect.  Everything you have here looks right.  There are a few incorrect answers in the back, so be careful.  I'm putting together all of the [solutions to apostol](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/index-of-solutions/solutions-to-calculus-exercises) and should note when the book answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The floor function is an example of a discontinuous integral. This means it can be done by splitting the integral. However, just to beef up this question ***let's compute the indefinite integral***. Then we'll be *forced* to deal with the discontinuity.

First off, floor itself is level everywhere. That means that we can use a sort of preliminary integral to get a function closer to our end result by simply holding floor fixed during integration. If you don't know what it means to hold something fixed, that's fine. You'll see in my calculations. Afterwards, we'll want to remove the jumps from the graph of the ***improper integral***. This will consist purely of me iterating through the ***points of discontinuity*** with a piecewise summation. The formula itself won't necessarily make sense without looking closely for a while (depending on your level of understanding in calculus), but it is the formula for removing discontinuity from step functions.

First we take the "integral"):

$$\int (-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor = x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor$$

Now we remove the discontinuity:

We use a notation called the iverson for this. It's just piecewise. Basically, it returns 1 when a math statement is fulfilled aka true, and 0 when not fulfilled aka false. It's literally just "[]".

**Don't use it on your homework without putting a note that it's an indicator function, though. The teacher's will nail to the wall for violating notation. Better yet, just ask them if you can use it and how they want it written.**

$$x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor - [x > 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} (\lim_{a \to n^+} (a(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \lfloor a \rfloor)-\lim_{a \to n^-} (a(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \lfloor a \rfloor)) + [x < 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} (\lim_{a \to n^-} (a(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \lfloor a \rfloor)-\lim_{a \to n^+} (a(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \lfloor a \rfloor))$$

Distribute limits:

$$x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor - [x > 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} ((n(-1)^{n}n)-(n(-1)^{n-1}(n-1))) + [x < 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} ((n(-1)^{n-1}(n-1))-(n(-1)^{n}n))$$

$$x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor - [x > 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} ((n(-1)^{n}n)+(n(-1)^{n}(n-1))) + [x < 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} (-(n(-1)^{n}(n-1))-(n(-1)^{n}n))$$

$$x(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor x \rfloor - [x > 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} (n(-1)^{n}(2n-1))) + [x < 0] \sum^{\lfloor x \rfloor}_{n=0} (-(n(-1)^{n}(2n-1)))$$

if one could please provide with the equation for that series, I can complete this integral. Otherwise, here is the indefinite integral. You can simply plug in values to solve your parts. As for part b.. The floor function has no inverse. So you'd have to play with it.